# Enable autoscale in plotly.r

Tags: r, r-markdown, shinydashboard, r-plotly, flexdashboard

In my flexdashboard I used "plotly" library to plot the graph. when the data is refreshing at that time the bar size get reduced. At that time when I clicked on "autoscale" option then it is working fine. My question is can we enable autoscale automatically by any option in plotly.r code ?

Answer (score 7):

Try setting `autorange = TRUE` for both the x- and y-axis in the `layout` option.

This solved the issue for me.

Example:

```
plot_ly(x, y, type = "bar") %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(autorange = TRUE),
         yaxis = list(autorange = TRUE))
```

For other plotly axes modifications in R check this [page](https://plot.ly/r/axes/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried using "autorange = TRUE" but still after sometimes in my dashboard the bar size get reduced.