# Enabling autoscale by default on a ggplotly object

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have converted several ggplot2 objects to plotly via the ggplotly command.

After the plot renders, and I publish to my Shiny server, I need to manually click "Autoscale" on the plot before it will autoscale. I want it to use this behaviour by default. I'm unsure exactly how to get the argument in there, and whether it is possible.

My current code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

plot1 <- ggplot(my_data, aes(x=month, y=views, colour=category)) + geom_line(size = 1)
ggplotly(plot1)
```

I'm unsure of the argument required, and cannot find documentation on how to exactly achieve this. Is anybody able to assist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596899/7547327

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552405/enable-autoscale-in-plotly-r

Answer (score 2):

The comments to your post point you in an appropriate direction, but the example there is slightly different because it does not involve calling `ggplotly` on a `ggplot` object. As it turns out, you can just pipe the layout argument:

```
ggplotly(plot1) %>% 
    layout(xaxis = list(autorange = TRUE), yaxis = list(autorange = TRUE))
```